# 3 month notice period in contract... better to negotiate to 1 month?

Tags: contracts, united-kingdom, notice-period

I'm a developer about to take a new position, however the contract states the notice period on both sides in the event of leaving the company is 3 months.

I am wondering if I should ask to have this reduced to 1 month, if possible.

The role is not 'senior' in title but is in reality (my previous have been senior). The company is forming a new team to do some work that differs from the rest of the developers there.

I can see that if this project goes belly-up and we were to be made redundant, then 3 months notice is beneficial to me as an employee. However in the event I should want to leave, I don't believe most employers are happy to wait three months for somebody to join.

Is it worth asking for the notice period to be reduced? Or am I missing something, and 3 months is better for me in reality?

Comment: Your question is impossible to answer without a lot of speculation in lieu of access to a crystal ball.

Comment: If they decide to get rid of you, would you like to have 31 days or 90 days to polish your CV, find companies which hire, craft cover letters, send out applications, allow them a week to respond, phone in, get invitation to the first interview, attend the interviews, get invitation to the second interview, which is postponed for two weeks because your manager-to-be is on vacation, attend the second interview, receive the offer, negotiate the bonus package, and finally start working again?

Comment: I've always found that 4 weeks is enough in IT to secure something new, unless you are looking for a very specific job. I'm concerned about the scenario whereby I wish to leave (more likely that the team/project being shut) and my next employer won't wait 3 months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 Month it too high when position is not senior. But It is depends on company policies and employee position. Many companies set notice period like 2 - 3 months for senior positions and there are many reasons behind that.

Here As you specified position is not senior then of course you can request them to reduce it and set to 1 month or 45 days. And you are taking new position so it is necessary to clear about notice period before set to position so in future it will not create any issue when you want to leave.

Comment: I don't know about this, it's likely standard in the company so possibly non-negotiable up front, but likely easier to agree when you look to leave.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager - I agree with you but some I have experienced with some companies which do not reduce notice period and follow notice period which set at time on joining.

Comment: Yes, but you make sure you're ready to go when the time comes, so they have no reason to keep hold of you.  Sitting playing angry birds as you have nothing to do is a great way to get them to reconsider.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager - Yeah you are right..:)

Comment: the position is Senior in practice

Answer (score 14):

This is becoming more common in the UK, but I'd hang fire as it works two ways.

If they were to fire you/cut your job/close down the office (assuming not for something like gross misconduct where it'd be summary dismissal), you would at least have 3 months to find something else.

Your next employer (after this upcoming one) won't be surprised by the three months notice (I've said "I have 3 months notice, but I'll see if I can negotiate it down"), and these things are always negotiable, I've managed to get out of them before, just make sure everything is tied up or ready to be handed over when you make the next move, it's really just a safety net for the employer.

Additionally asking up front makes you look like your planning your escape before even joining, which may make your new employer jumpy.  Wait until you need to.

Comment: For senior professional jobs 3 months is not uncommon depends on the industry and custom and practice in the company.

Comment: It's been common for senior roles for a while, but it's becoming more common across the board, certainly in IT.

Comment: I'm concerned that hiring managers won't wait three months. This role isn't senior in title, and no managerial tasks, but more like a large part in a small team.

Answer (score 0):

3 months only benefits the employer in this industry. If you are made redundant then you will find somewhere else far easier when working out a month rather than 3. And if you can't find another job, what difference is two months going to make anyway?

That's the least likely scenario though. Most likely is you want to leave them, and when you want to go, you want to go sooner than 3 months.

And honestly if they want to get rid of you sooner, they can. They could for example post you to some random office (look out for that clause in contract) and when you don't want to, they can negotiate an early departure.

I tried to negotiate this down in one offer from 3 months to 6 weeks, they said no, they can't make exceptions. So I turned the job down. Then they wanted to discuss it! It's a risky game, but for me it's a deal breaker.

Comment: I did the same - turned them down for a place that was more flexible.