# 3-months notice period, only 1 month notice payment: How to negotiate notice period so as to a month for both side?

Tags: job-offer, united-kingdom, notice-period

I have received a permanent job offer (geography: United Kingdom), which includes a 3-months notice period clause. There's also an unusual clause stating that the employer may claim damages if the employee don't serve the complete notice period.

Is it common in permanent roles for the employer to go after leavers and try to obtain financial damages for notice period related matters?

Although the word *senior* is mentioned in the job title, there's nothing extraordinary about the position; it's just another software engineering role.

Also, there's a clause that states they can terminate the contract at any time by giving a payment of 30 days.

So before signing the contract should I negotiate with them to reduce the notice period to 1 month?

Comment: Remove the question " Is there a common law that supersedes it?" and this may be fit for the site.  I think it's a valid question - should the same notice period apply to both sides? Is it fair that you have to give 3 months notice but the employer only needs to give you a month?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Not sure why you want to close this. when similar question by somebody else is already present here: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/44277/3-month-notice-period-in-contract-better-to-negotiate-to-1-month?rq=1

Comment: @user6176517 nope, those other questions ask about negotiating, you are asking strictly for help to interpret a contract and even directly for common law precedence, and for that, you need a lawyer and is off topic here.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul As suggested by somebody above, I am willing to remove the common law sentence. Would you be kind enough to remove the block on the question? as its really pressing & I would like to get answer from UK community. Cheers

Comment: @user6176517 that's up for people to vote on whether to repon, though without the legal question, how is this one differnt from the question you've linked, so to not constitue a duplicate?

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul In my question, I am asking about differential payment in-lieu. i.e. although notice period is stated as 3 months but payment is only 1 month

Comment: In the UK, I would never, ever, ever accept a contractual penalty for not serving the notice period. I would also never accept notice periods that are not the same for both sides.

Comment: @gnasher729 Thanks. But how to navigate in current pressed pandemic situation? Could you please help in reopening this question? Thanks

Comment: @user6176517, This is a red flag. I would be outraged if I were you! Even if you could change the contract to a one month notice on both sides, do you really want to work for an employer like that? If they're going to treat you like that before the contract is signed, what else are they going to try while you're working for them. If you accept such a job (even with the modified contract), you really deserve what's coming to you.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk But how to survive in current pressed pandemic situation, as there're fewer options available. Could you please help in reopening this question, so that we could get more answers? Thanks

Comment: My advice would be to just walk away from this abusive employer and not even look back. But if you really want me to vote to reopen the question, you'll have to change your question. Instead of asking "So before signing the contract should I negotiate with them to reduce the notice period to 1 month?", ask "How should I negotiate with them to reduce the notice period to one month on both sides? Also, I don't want to have to buy malpractice insurance, how do I argue against being liable for "any loss suffered by the Company arising from [my] failure to work [my] full contractual notice"?

Comment: And please stop asking us how to survive the job market in a pandemic situation, we're all in the same boat as you. Many of us will apply for help from the government, go to a food bank, move back in with our family, sleep on a friend's floor, sleep in our cars, or become homeless, if we have to, just because many of us don't want to get stuck with an abusive employer. It's just a choice we make. If we didn't have such choices in our lives, we'd all be drug dealers, gas station robbers, or street hookers.

Comment: StephanBranzyk Thanks. I've edited the title (tried to put as much, based on characters limit)

Answer (score 4):

> There's also an unusual clause stating that the employer may claim
>   damages if the employee don't serve the complete notice period.

I've seen that before.

> Is it common in permanent roles for the employer to go after leavers
>   and try to obtain financial damages for notice period related matters?
>   Is there a common law that supersedes it?

It is for more menial jobs(1) and if the employee is not leaving on good terms. It depends entirely on the company/leaver.

> So before signing the contract should I negotiate with them to reduce
>   the notice period to 1 month?

Yes, if you like. Everything is negotiable. I would cite inconsistencies within the contractual terms, rather than "I don't like it".

Is there another clause which states that the contract can be terminated for any reason within the first n months?

My feeling in such matters is that I would sign anything which is fair and equal to both parties. I would either get the notice period reduced or the termination period increased or stricken from the contract.

---

(1) I have a friend who is a chef who went through this for a number of jobs over a succession of years. I got to know the employment lawyers quite well as my friend is functionally illiterate and needed a lot of support.

Comment: It also states that - 'Organization may deduct from any final monies owing to you any
additional cost of covering your duties for the period not worked or an amount equal to any loss
suffered by the Company arising from your failure to work your full contractual notice.' Is it limited risk ringfensed by withheld salary payment or is it unlimited risk?

Comment: some useful article : https://www.crunch.co.uk/knowledge/employment/pay-and-wages-pay-cuts-protection-from-unauthorised-deductions-from-your-pay-2/

Comment: @user6176517 I've never seen that (Organization may deduct...) clause in any employment contract OR services contract (I'm an IT contractor). DO NOT sign this. Seek advice from Citizen's Advice Bureau. In my opinion this is a serious red flag, and reason enough to walk away from this "opportunity".

Comment: I talked to a lawyer & they said such clause is anyways implied whether explicitly written or not.